# Unable to read a directory using File.list()

Tags: java, perl, io

I was hoping to get a list of all files and folders in a directory using java without using system calls.

I tried:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
File fileDir = new File("directory");
String[] fileNames = fileDir.list();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileDir.list()));
}
}
```

But it only returned 9 files out of many more. I tried with a Perl script and got the same result. I think there is something wrong with the directory, but I'm at a loss as to what.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: How did you determine that there is much more? Can you provide full path to directory and names of missing files?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at wrong directory -> mind you are using relative path, which might be different than what you expect (print out fileDir.getAbsolutePath() to find out).

Comment: In the end it was an incorrect path. Two folders existed with similar names, and nearly identical folder structures. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a file object pointing at "directory" means that the file object will end up pointing to `<jvm running directory>/directory` . The jvm running directory is generally whatever directory you launch the jvm from. Try using the full path to the directory and see if it works.

Otherwise, please provide some sample output as well as the expected output.